# Inkscape: add nodes at extrema without increasing the total number (approx)

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape you can add nodes at the extrema in each of the selected path segments. This can be highly convenient e.g. when you want to design glyphs for a font. However it can strongly increase the number of nodes in that path without really changing the geometry. Some programs suffer dramatically from a high number of nodes. In my case it is a complex symbol for a font that already contains many nodes (unlike letters).

So it would be nice to remove redundant nodes. `Path`|`Simplify` does exactly this (Although I had to lower the Simplification threshold to 0.0006). However it doesn't care about extremes and so it removes most of the previously added nodes.

Is it possible to decrease the number of nodes after adding extrema to approximately the same amount it was before without removing the extrema and without changing the shape too much?

Comment: Unfortunately the only methods I've seen so far are *Path > Simplify* and just deleting individual nodes manually. This happens to me a lot too. Usually what I do is delete extraneous nodes as I create them.

Comment: Hmm, okay then I guess that'll be something I have to do manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is **no**.

What you are asking for is to restrict the scope of the Simplify Path operation, which is currently not possible. Simplify Path works on the entire path.

Your best option is to simplify the path manually as you work, meaning delete duplicate or unnecessary nodes as you go.

There are actually [quite a few shortcuts](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys045.html#Node%20tool) that you can use with the Node Tool <kbd>F2</kbd> though. Using some of those shortcuts may make the processes of cleaning up your nodes easier.